# Recent apps button reset stack in my app

Tags: android

I have a simple app in Android Studio with 3 activities.

Splash > Login > Details

In the Details Activity, if I press the back button, the app goes to Home.

But if I choose from recents apps button, the activity start in Login.

The code for close and start is simple:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

I tried with:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

and

```
if (!isTaskRoot())
{
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String intentAction = intent.getAction(); 
    if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
        finish();
        return;       
    }
}
```

and many others options, but nothing work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [android:alwaysRetainTaskState](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) in your root activity